# array and operator overloading within a struct ,from c++ to c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-c++, struct, operator-overloading

I try to convert this c++ code to c# :

```
struct gene 
{
int alleles[4];
int fitness;
float likelihood;

    // Test for equality.
    int operator==(gene gn) 
    {
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            if (gn.alleles[i] != alleles[i]) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

bcs in C# inform me that I can not make array within struct in addition to error in operator == overloading,so, how its will be in c#?

Comment: You should be providing the solution that you have if you want us to help you fix it.

Comment: Don't use `struct` in C#, use `class` instead. It is *not* the same as C++ `class`/`struct` difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operators in C# needs to be public static. Also the == operator needs two objects as argument to be able to compare, and an != operator also needs to be defined if a == operator is to be defined.

Try this:

```
public struct Gene
{
    int[] alleles;
    int fitness;
    float likelihood;

    public Gene(int[] alleles) : this()
    {
        this.alleles = alleles;
    }

    // Test for equality.
    public static bool operator ==(Gene gn1, Gene gn2) 
    {
        for (int i=0; i < gn1.alleles.Length ;i++)
        {
            if (gn1.alleles[i] != gn2.alleles[i]) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Gene gn1, Gene gn2)
    {
        return !(gn1 == gn2);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much , for helping in understanding and solving , my greetings for you , But if i can ask , how can i make fixed size for array same to alleles[4]? may be needed to add constructor? or ?

Comment: Yes I think adding it to the constructor is the best solution. I added it to my answer.